# How do I tell IntelliJ IdeaVim to re-source the .ideavimrc

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I made some changes to my `.ideavimrc` and I want IntelliJ IdeaVim to reload the file.  I can obviously close and reopen IntelliJ, but that sucks.

How can I re-source my `.ideavimrc` without restarting IntelliJ?

Comment: Where can I find list of Rider commands?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

In Intellij's code editor window while in command mode, type a colon, that opens up a mini bar at the bottom. Then type:

```
:source ~/.ideavimrc
```

Comment: And as a bonus, map that command to an ideaVIM keystroke: `nnoremap <leader>si :source ~/.ideavimrc<CR>`

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work on Windows. I've tried with fully qualified path too, e.g. `:source C:\Users\user\.ideavimrc`

Comment: @StevenPribilinskiy it works if you use `/` instead of ``\`` in the path

Answer (score 13):

After editing the .ideavimrc file, you can click the reload button (or press Shift + Cmd + l) to resource it:

[image]

Comment: The whole point of using IntelliJ stuff is to benefit from everything the IDEA offers. Thank you!

Comment: I like this answer better. Click on the IdeaVim icon in the bottom status bar and click Open ~/.ideavimrc. Once you make edits to the file, it gives you the option to reload as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have the following handly key binds.

```
nnoremap \e :e ~\.ideavimrc<CR>
nnoremap \r :action IdeaVim.ReloadVimRc.reload<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

Now you can simply press Cmd+Shift+I while editing the .ideavimrc file or press the icon in the top right ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYxlR.png))

Comment: Tip: if your IdeaVim icon is missing, go to Actions and toggle "Show IdeaVim" to on, or right click another item on the status bar (which is where it is for me) and select IdeaVim.